# Render HtmlGenericControl from a HttpHandler

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, httphandler

I have a set of code (noted below) in `ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)` in a generic handler `.ashx` file.

```
HtmlGenericControl holder = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
//Set holder's properties and customization
HtmlGenericControl button1 = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
//Set button1's properties and customization
holder.Controls.Add(button1);
HtmlGenericControl button2 = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
//Set button2's properties and customization
holder.Controls.Add(button2);
HtmlGenericControl button2 = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
//Set button2's properties and customization
holder.Controls.Add(button2);
```

Now as I am in a `HttpHander`, I want to get the `HTML` of `holder` control and write it through `context.Respose.Write()`.

Please help me through this.
Thanks in advance

Munim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the way by myself.

```
using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
    holder.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
    HttpContext.Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
    htmlTextWriter.Close();
    stringWriter.Close();
}
```